# Method checking to show function is discontinuous at x=0

Tags: continuity

Let $f:[0, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x \sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x} \cos \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$. Is $f$ continuous ?

> my method was that x $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ has limit value as zero as x tends to zero . So we can focus on just the  $\frac{1}{x} \cos \frac{1}{x}$ , that term is having the form if infinity * some number between -1 and 1 , both inclusive , so we can say its indeterminate hence limit doesnt exist ? Or we cannot do this method as when we apply partwise limit check we need to ensure both limit exists?

Comment: I recommend that you try to find a sequence of numbers $x_n\to0$ with the property that $\cos(1/x_n)=1$ for each $n$. What then are the resulting values of $f(x_n)$?

Comment: Okay i will surely try it , from a glance it seems we need to take x_n to be 1/(2pi n), but can you once tell if my original method was correct or not ? I mean i think its wrong becaue i took limit f(x) = limit of both indicidual limits without showing that both should exist then only we could have had applied this method ? @MarkMcClure

Comment: It looks like there's an answer that correctly addresses the problematic issues with your approach. I would also point out that $\sin(x)=0$ when $\cos(x)=1$. Thus, there's no need to break the problem up by dealing with the summands separately.

Comment: I am sorry but yeah i agree that sinx = 0 when cosx =1 , but how it tells that  summand is not needed to be considered separately we dont know the exact varation as its of form cos(infinity) and sin(infinity) Sir ?

Comment: Your method is correct (+1), but you need to fix it a litte. The last term consists of product of two factors one of which tends to $\infty$ and the other one oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ (you used $0,1$ inclusive and that is insufficient to conclude). So effectively the term oscillates infinitely.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Paramanand Singh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a mistake to say the function  'is indeterminate' – the expression you're considering is defined for $x\ne 0$, where $\frac 1x$ is well defined, its cosine $\cos\frac 1x$ is well defined and their product is well defined, too.

You should rather point out that cosine's range $[-1,1]$ (not $[0,1],$ btw) allows values of the subexpression to reach from $-\frac 1{|x|}$ to $\frac 1{|x|}$, which gets unbounded when $x$ approaches zero.

That implies $f$ is unbounded around $x=0$ which breaks the condition in the limit's definition.
As a result, $f$ has no limit at $x=0.$

Comment: Is it always true btw Sir that suppose h(x) = f(x) +g(x)   and we are assuming limit of h(x) to exist , we also know that limit of f(x) surely exists and i have the value of that already . , If we showed that limit g(x) doesnt exist. This will imply limit h(x) which we assumed to exist is defintely not existing?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer: I think that you should state the definition of 'discontinuous' in the OP. Some people use '$f$ is discontinuous at $a$' to mean that $f$ is either not defined at $a$ or $f$ is not continuous at $a$ (if it is defined there). User CiaPan seems to be using the definition that -$f$ is said to be discontinuous at $a$ if $a$ is in domain of $f$ and $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer: Please note that with the former definition $x\mapsto 1/x$ is discontinuous at $0$ but w.r.t. the other definition $x\mapsto 1/x$ is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: @Koro you are very right , i should have mentioned the def of discontinuous i am using . But yeah i agree with all yours points , very very thanks for providing insights

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer (1/2) User Koro is right. I am so used to the "limit=value" definition that I overlooked the other possibility. They are both mentioned e.g. in Wikipedia article [Continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) in section _Definition in terms of limits of functions_ and in _Definition in terms of neighborhoods_, respectively.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer (2/2) The very same article uses them both inconsitently, for example the caption of an image in _Real functions_, _Definition_ says $x\mapsto 1/x$ is continuous over its domain, but discontinuous at $x=0$, whilst a similar rational function in _Construction of continuous functions_ is said to be continuous, just not defined at $x=-2.$

Comment: Understood @CiaPan , can you once check what i posted in the first comment in this answer of yours Sir?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer No, if functions $f, g, h$ are defined on the same neighborhood of some value $p,$ and they satisfy $h(x)=f(x)+g(x),$ and both $f$ and $g$ have a limit at $p$, then their sum also has a limit there and the limit of the sum equals the sum of limits: $\lim_{x\to p}h(x) = \lim_{x\to p}f(x) + \lim_{x\to p}g(x).$ So it's not possible for one of them to have no limit while other two have limits. OTOH it's possible one has a limit and two do not have limits.

Comment: Yeah Sir so what i am saying was that by **assumption of h(x) limit being exist** , although f(x) is existing as earlier said, we get limit of  g(x) to be existing from the sum and difference rule of limits , but if that g(x) limit is not existing , so that is contradicting the first assumption , hence limit of h(x) is not existing ?? I am appying this here where we know f(x)= xsin(1/x) has finite limit , while h(x) we at start assumed it , but if that is true , g(x) = 1/x cos(1/x) should also have a finite limit but thats not true , hence h(x) limit doesnt exist ?

Answer (score 2):

In order for
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x} \cos \left( \frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
to be continuous at $x=0$, we must have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = 0.
$$
In particular, we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = 0,
$$
for every real sequence $(x_n)$ that tends to zero.

Now, consider $\displaystyle x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}$. Note that
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{2n\pi}\right) = \frac{1}{2n\pi}\,\sin(2n\pi) + 2n\pi\cos(2npi) = 2n\pi \not\to 0.
$$
Thus, for this particular sequence satisfying $x_n\to0$, we *don't* have $f(x_n)\to0$. Thus, $f$ is not continuous at zero.